# Select from table where value does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table (`country_table`) with a list of all countries and their respective ids.

```
|country_id|country_name|
|ES        |Spain       |
.
.
.
```

I have an array, fetched from another table using `fetch_array` that looks like this:

```
$array = Array(
    [0]=>Array([country_id]=>'ES')
    [1]=>Array([country_id]=>'DE')
    [2]=>Array([country_id]=>'GB'))
```

How can I select the records (country_id and country_name) from `country_table` that do not exist in the table but exist in the array?

Comment: Mate, I got really confused reading your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql ="SELECT country_id, country_name FROM country_table
       WHERE country_id NOT IN (". implode(",", $array) .")";
```

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function will generate comma-seprated string representation of array elements .

Answer (score 0):

This is the sql.

```
select country_id, country_name from table where country_id not in ('ES','DE','GB');
```

Comment: I figured that out. But how can i implement this using the above array

Comment: I didn't answer because you didn't tell us what mysql driver you are using. Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

```
// gather unwanted id's first
$notInIds = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) $notInIds[] = $arr['country_id'];

// prepare query
$query = 'SELECT `country_id`, `country_name` FROM `your_table`
WHERE `country_id` NOT IN (' . implode(',',$notInIds) . ')';

// then execute it
```

Answer (score 0):

For the question: "How can I select the records (country_id and country_name) from country_table **that do *not* exist in the table** but **exist in the array**?"

I guess you have to write some code (eg. in PHP) in order to achieve the result you want.
The problem is that you can not display data that is not in the table (eg. country_name), that's not possible as you don't know this data. The only possibility would to show the country_id's which are in the array and not in the table as this is the only data you have...